# On a raspberry pi how to launch a python script via crontab as we would do in SSH?

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, screen-size

I have a python script that uses the 'os' library to find the screen size. This script works fine when I run it in SSH but it crashes if I try to run it with crontab.

my python script :

```
import os
screen_resolution = os.popen("xrandr | grep '*' | awk '{print $1}'").read().strip().split("x")
screen_width = int(screen_resolution[0])
screen_height = int(screen_resolution[1])
print("Screen Resolution : ", screen_width, "x", screen_height)
```

crontab :
`@reboot python /home/pi/Documents/run.py > /home/pi/log.log 2>&1t`
or
`@reboot env DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority python /home/pi/Documents/run.py > /home/pi/log.log 2>&1`

error log :

```
Can't open display 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/run.py", line 4, in <module>
    screen_width = int(screen_resolution[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Is there a way to run this kind of script once the whole system has booted ?
Because I have the impression that by going through cron some of the environment variables have not yet been configured

I tried to pass it variables display and Xauthority in crontab but without success.
I would like to execute this script automatically when you launch by hand via SSH

Comment: Edit the title to be in English.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can more easily determine the resolution of the attached monitor using this command:

```
/usr/bin/tvservice -s
state 0xa [HDMI DMT (87) RGB full 15:9], 1024x600 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
```

That doesn't require an X11 server to be running, or any authorisation or DISPLAY setting.

You may want to extract just the resolution like this:

```
/usr/bin/tvservice -s | grep -Po '(?<=,\s)\d+x\d+'
1024x600
```

---

Another option is:

```
/usr/bin/vcgencmd get_lcd_info
1024 600 24
```

Comment: `pi@rpi:~ $ /usr/bin/tvservice -s | grep -Po '(?<=,\s)\d+x\d+'
/usr/bin/tvservice is not supported when using the vc4-kms-v3d driver.
Similar features are available with standard linux tools
such as modetest from libdrm-tests.
pi@rpi:~ $ /usr/bin/vcgencmd get_lcd_info
0 0 0 no display`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the autostart file

```
nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

thanks

Comment: Please explain what you changed in that file. Saying you edited it doesn't really help. Thank you.